# IModelValidator dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP .NET Core, how can I get access to DI in the `Validate` method of an `IModelValidator`?

Example:

```cs
public class RollercoasterPassenger
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

public class RollercoasterPassengerValidatorAttribute : Attribute, IModelValidator
{
    public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelValidationContext context)
    {
        var model = (RollercoasterPassenger)context.Model;
        var minimumHeightProvider = (IMinimumHeightProvider)null; //get IMinimumHeightProvider somehow!!!
        var minimumHeight = minimumHeightProvider.GetMinimumHeight();
        if (model.Height < minimumHeight)
            yield return new ModelValidationResult("Height", $"You must be at least {minimumHeight} to ride");
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ModelValidationContext Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.modelvalidationcontext) has access to the current request's context.

```
//...

//get IMinimumHeightProvider somehow!!!
var minimumHeightProvider = context.ActionContext
    .HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMinimumHeightProvider>(); 

//...
```

This is more of a service locator approach